# Xubuntu 14.04 and ConnectPro UD-12+ DDM KVM Switch - display won't wake

Tags: 14.04, kvm-virtualization

I have a DDM ConnectPro UD-12+ KVM switch.

I use it with a Win 7 machine and a dual-boot machine running both Win 7 and Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

When using it to switch between the Win 7 installs, it works great. If I use it between the Win 7 box and the Trusty Tahr install, the display on the Tahr install won't wake.

I eventually found a workaround; I memorized the key commands to log out and back in. This (tedious) method will wake the display.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, *insert password here*, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
*The machine displays login at this point, but I have to enter the password again*

When running various Xubuntu and Ubuntu Studio live disks (including on the Win 7 box), the problem still occurs.

Today I replaced the Win7 box, which is now dual boot with Xubuntu 17.04
Zesty Zapus, and 17.04 is perfectly fine with the KVM; it's working really well, and I'm really happy with it.
*However*, for the time being I need to leave 14.04 on the other box.

I've had a lot of trouble locating information about this issue, so I figured it might be a good idea to get an account here and get the issue up in case someone else is looking for it.

And, of course, I want to fix it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cheap KVM switch (DVI) myself, between Windows and Xubuntu 16.04.

When switching to Xubuntu there would be no signal to monitor.

Another workaround is shifting to tty1 CTRL+ALT+F1 (or one of the others 2-6 with F2-6) before switching away with KVM. After switching back with KVM CTRL+ALT+F7 to get back on desktop.

If forgotten and signal is lost

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

will from one of the tty's reset back to GUI for me.

I have not understood or figured out a solution from the bugs mentioned in comments.

Comment: I just found this. It looks like a clue.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1308105

Comment: This seems to be the same issue.
https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11107